# rails 6 jquery not working in production error says $ isn't defined

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, webpacker

I'm getting the error $ isn't defined in production only The error doesn't occur in development and $ is defined in config/webpack/environment.js

```
    const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')
    // const customConfig = require('./custom');
    const webpack = require('webpack')

    environment.plugins.prepend('Provide',
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
         $: "jquery",
        jQuery: "jquery",
        Popper: ['popper.js', 'default']
    }),)

    const aliasConfig = {
    'jquery': 'jquery-ui-dist/external/jquery/jquery.js',
    'jquery-ui': 'jquery-ui-dist/jquery-ui.js'
    };

    environment.config.set('resolve.alias', aliasConfig);

    module.exports = environment
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add to your `app/javascript/packs/application.js`:

```
global.$ = require("jquery")
```